# Upgrading to Angular 13 with NX monorepo broke custom ng schematics

Tags: angular, nrwl, angular-schematics, nomachine-nx

I'm extending @nrwl/schematics to create a custom Angular component schematic. After running `nx migrate latest`, `npm i`, then `nx migrate --run-migrations=migrations.json`, I get the following error when attempting to generate a new component:

`NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID`

My schema.json uses "$id" property so I'm not sure why it's complaining. I suspect it's possibly because @nrwl/schematics uses version 8 of Angular schematics?

My schematic setup worked fine on Angular 12 - any thoughts?